# Which object reference does $this contain in this SLIM code?

Tags: php, twig, slim

I m trying to render a simple HTML view using the twig-view of SLIM. I want to know that when i route using the get() function

```
//Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

//Register Component on container

$container['view'] = function($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('templates', [
    'cache' => false
    ]);

    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
    $container['router'],
    $container['request']->getUri()
    ));

    return $view;

};

$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'index.html');
});

$app->run();
```

Then which object reference $this contains.
Please help me to clarify. Thankyou

Comment: try dump($this); die();

Comment: it is giving Slim\Container. But now i want to ask how this closure function gets access to the Container object. I mean i haven't passed it and not even included the use() with the closure to reference the container object.Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SlimFramework docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-groups) :

> Note inside the group closure, `$this` is used instead of `$app`. Slim
>   binds the closure to the application instance for you, just like it is
>   the case with route callback binds with container instance.
>
> - inside group closure, `$this` is bound to the instance of `Slim\App`
> - inside route closure, `$this` is bound to the instance of `Slim\Container`

Answer (score 2):

`$this` is the dependency injection container of slim: [`Slim\Container`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Container.php)

Inside the [`DeferredCallable`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/DeferredCallable.php), you can see that slim uses the [`bindTo`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) function on the closure to set the `$this` instance.

Comment: But now i want to ask how this closure function gets access to the Container object. I mean i haven't passed it and not even included the use() with the closure to reference the container object.Please help me out

Comment: this means Slim is returning its own closure when we call for the clousure as a parameter deciding by its own the context to which to refer. Is it so @jmattheis

Comment: No slim uses the closure you give when you use `$app->post`, get or whatever and sets the container instance to it with bindTo

Answer (score -1):

`$this` points to the class where the closure is created

```
class a {
    public function test(){
       //closure is defined in the class
       return function(){
            print_r($this);//so you have access to $this
       };
    }
}

$a = new a();
$a->test();
```

In your example you are using https://www.slimframework.com/ and there it works not in that way. But so it works basicly in php.

Comment: @jmattheis I used the word `seems` to note that.